# UITableView Grouped table border issue

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am creating a grouped table with two sections.In the first section i have 5 cells and in the second section i have two buttons in the lass cell of it.

I have created labels and buttons on each of the cells in the first section and the labels are populated dynamically by the values selected in the previous screen.

Everything works fine as expected,except the borders of the table view gets ruined,it looks like half drawn and incomplete.When i make the table view to scroll up and when its back in the original position,the top borders are spoiled and when i scroll to the bottom the lower borders of the group gets affected making them incomplete.

I am setting the label's and button's attributes in each of cell after initializing them in the viewDidLoad method.

Please suggest me an idea to solve this issue.

Thank you one and all

Comment: A screenshot would be really helpful here, can you provide one?

Answer (score 0):

> I am setting the label's and button's attributes in each of cell after
>   initializing them in the viewDidLoad method.

This is incorrect. You should save the texts for the labels & buttons in a model class & set them in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. As, you are not doing this in the aforementioned method, your cell is redrawn when you scroll and the texts are nullified.